# fetching the same data to two select elements

Tags: javascript, fetch

i'm new to java script and i have a problem:

so i want to get data from an API and display it in two select elements(the two select will have to same options from the API), the problem is is only the second select get the values and not the one .

```
const dropDown1 = document.querySelector('#select1');
const dropDown2 = document.querySelector('#select2');

getData().then(data => {

    Object.entries(data.results).forEach(element => {
        let currId = document.createElement('option');

        currId.innerText = element[1].id;
        dropDown1.appendChild(currId);
        dropDown2.appendChild(currId);

    });

})
```

if i comment "dropDown2.appendChild(currId);" the first select will get the data , so i don't know why.
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending the node moves it from one parent to another, you can [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the node before appending it to the 2nd dropdown:

```
const dropDown1 = document.querySelector('#select1');
const dropDown2 = document.querySelector('#select2');

getData().then(data => {
  Object.entries(data.results).forEach(element => {
      let currId = document.createElement('option');
      currId.innerText = element[1].id;

      dropDown1.appendChild(currId);
      dropDown2.appendChild(currId.cloneNode());    
  });
})
```